# Can articles of impeachment be repealed?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, impeachment

Suppose the House of Representatives of the United States impeaches a federal officer such as the president or a federal judge, etc. Can they repeal that act before the Senate tries the case?

Answer (score 4):

It's never happened so there is really no definitive answer. There are plausible arguments both ways.

Many impeachment cases have been dismissed in the Senate before a trial is complete, or before a Senate trial is commenced, because a resignation has made the process moot.

Comment: Concerning your second paragraph: How many? Which ones? Does "many" mean about six, or more like six-hundred, or what?

Comment: Since one of the consequences of conviction by the Senate can be disqualification from holding federal offices in the future, it the officer resigns before the end of the trial, it seems that doesn't make the process altogether moot.

Comment: @MichaelHardy There have been about two dozen impeachments in the history of the USA. There's a complete list in an answer i did a year or two ago in Politics.SE About a third or a quarter have been dismissed. I'd have to look up the exact number.

Comment: That will be https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/25682/10121 .

Comment: See also: "[Can the US Senate disqualify a former President?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/45157/427)" (about the case of resignation before disqualification.)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a complete answer to me. "There are plausible arguments both ways". What are those arguments? What would be the legal authority for those arguments? Etc.